# Why I can't launch Android emulator after i make the source of Android 6.0?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I make the source of Android 6.0 according to google's document, and after I typing

```
emulator
```

I got the following output:

`emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (1536 MB > 200 MB)`

`emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (550 MB > 200 MB)`

`emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB`

`Warning: No DNS servers found`

`emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get a URL: 6 (Error)`

`emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version 'invalid'`

Only a big (beyond the size of emulator) "Android" was shown on the emulator. After several minutes, even the startup animation stopped. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to starting emulator from the command line using this command

```
emulator.exe -avd <avd_name> -no-audio -http-proxy <proxy_name>:<proxy_port>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it may not caused by the net problem, when I can access Internet, the emulator still cannot start.

Comment: @张建浩 you are  trying  or not ?

Comment: it seems work.. amazing. but although the emulator started, it cannot response to my operation

Comment: Ok, the emulator seems run successfully this time, however, could you tell me why it works?

Comment: @张建浩 sometime it happen so we have use command to work with it. Now you can mark it as Accepted. so it help other person.

Comment: But you still haven't say why the "-no-audio" and "-http-proxy" help this problem..

Comment: @张建浩 `-no-audio` means `Disable audio support in the current emulator instance.`

Comment: @张建浩 `-http-proxy <proxy>` means `Make all TCP connections through a specified HTTP/HTTPS proxy`

Comment: @张建浩 now you get it .

Answer (score 0):

---

how much Ram u have allocated to that emulater make it 1028 mb or 768 mb(Actually it is the value )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know how to see these values when I launch emulator in command line.. I tried "emulator -memory 1300",  in that case the third warning was gone, but the emulator still cannot start.